# Why is this very simple MySQL query returning every row?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a very very simple MySQL query that will fetch any rows where field **pab_sku** (of data type `varchar(255)`) of table **product_attributes_basic** is equal to a relatively short list of values. For some reason, this query is returning every row in the table.

(Aside: I am using MySQL Workbench, which has worked well for much more complex queries.)

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR 'def';
```

The above returns every row in the entire table (several dozen thousand).

When I query for either string individually, no records are returned. (Which is correct; these are nonsense values.)

I've tried removing the apostrophes, but this has no effect; all rows return.

This is so simple that I'm at a loss as to a next step. Why on earth is this query returning every row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is it's not splitting as you expect.

```
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR 'def';
```

Is not the same as

```
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def';
```

Your code, written in a wordy way actually means

```
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR WHERE 'def'
```

`WHERE 'def'` then just gets evaluated as always `True`.

So you need to tell it explicitly that you're checking that value against `pab_sku` in both cases. With one of the following as others have suggested:

```
WHERE (pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def');
WHERE pab_sku IN ('abc', 'def');
```

Comment: mysql docs on logical operators: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I kept making such a simple/dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write column name again

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def'
```

Or use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku IN ('abc', 'def')
```

Comment: Good idea of using IN

Comment: It's a good idea to explain why this is the case, so the asker understands the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR 'def';
```

The OR in this case is not looking at the row values at all, basically the syntax is valid but it's not doing what you think it's doing.

change to:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def';
```

Comment: Please explain the difference in your question so the asker can understand their mistake.

Comment: because 'def' by itself means, that 'def' = 'def', and its true, and now we explicitly say that when AND only WHEN pab_sky = 'def'

Comment: Please edit that into your answer. Supplying working code is actually less important than teaching the idea behind the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def';
```

Comment: but im interested on how this works, please explaiin `WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR 'def';`

Comment: I think it's interpreting 'def' as a Boolean value.  In that case, it might be interpreted as True.  Any value OR True is always True.  The purpose of the OR is to join two expressions, so in this case, the two expressions are: 1) pab_sku = 'abc', and 2) 'def'.

Comment: yah i know it is boolean, i want to know why `abc` or `def` was interpreted as boolean true

Comment: 'def' isn't really a boolean value.  It doesn't directly map to 'true' or 'false', so you get whatever the parser happens to assign it to.  In the case of MySQL, it maps all non-zero values to True.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add the explanation from your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE (pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def');
```

This because you have to apply your logical function OR not only to the strings but applied to your column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes_basic
WHERE pab_sku = 'abc' OR pab_sku = 'def';
```

Comment: Please explain the difference in your question so the asker can understand their mistake.